# How can I refactor / make this code more pythonic?

Tags: python

I have a small program which makes uses of pycparser to parse C header files. The code, unfornatuley, kinda sprawls out everywhere to handle the different cases (example below).

What's the best way to make this more Pythonic? I thought about case-statements, but those don't exist in Python. Is splitting the function into smaller functions the best approach?

```
def build_struct(decl):
    """ Recursively builds a structure from external definition.
    """
    _type = type(decl)
    if _type == TypeDecl:
        return build_struct(decl.type)
    elif _type == IdentifierType:
        return " ".join(decl.names)
    elif _type == ID:
        return ['ID', decl.name]
    elif _type == Struct:
        struct = c_types.structureDefinition()
        for d in decl.decls:
            field = build_struct(d)
            struct.add_field(field)
        return struct
    elif _type == Union:
        union = c_types.unionDefinition()
        for d in decl.decls:
            field = build_struct(d)
            union.add_field(field)
        return union
    elif _type == Enum:
        # not implemented yet... but don't raise an exception
        # unsure if there is any value in supporting enums
        return
    else:
        nested = build_struct(decl.type)
        if _type == Decl:
            if decl.bitsize:
                # fields with bitsize defined (i.e. valid:1)
                return c_types.fieldDefinition(decl.name,
                                               int(decl.bitsize.value))
            elif isinstance(nested, c_types.structureDefinition):
                # if it's a structure, assign it's name
                nested.name = decl.name
                return nested
            elif isinstance(nested, c_types.unionDefinition):
                # if it's a union, assign it's name
                nested.name = decl.name
                return nested
            elif isinstance(nested, int):
                # if it's an array, we will just return the total size
                return c_types.fieldDefinition(decl.name, nested)
            else:
                # fields w/o bitsized defined
                id = nested
                # using defined types, like uint32_t
                if id in c_types.size_d:
                    size = c_types.size_d[id]
                # using defined structures, like fast_ip
                elif id in c_types.structs:
                    return c_types.structs[id]
                else:
                    raise c_types.UnknownIdentifier(id)
                # regular fields, i.e. int count;
                return c_types.fieldDefinition(decl.name, int(size))

        elif _type == Typename:  # for function parameters
            raise c_types.NotImplemented
        elif _type == ArrayDecl:
            #raise c_types.NotImplemented
            dimval = decl.dim.value if decl.dim else ''
            id = nested
            # using defined types, like uint32_t
            if id in c_types.size_d:
                size = c_types.size_d[id]
            # using defined structures, like fast_ip
            elif id in c_types.structs:
                return c_types.structs[id]
            else:
                raise c_types.UnknownIdentifier(id)
            return int(dimval) * size
        elif _type == PtrDecl:
            raise c_types.NotImplemented
        elif _type == Typedef:
            id = nested
            # TODO -- this is very common... refactor
            if isinstance(id, c_types.structureDefinition):
                # typedef struct ...
                # TODO -- very similar to code above...
                id.name = decl.name
                return id
            if isinstance(id, c_types.unionDefinition):
                # typedef struct ...
                # TODO -- very similar to code above...
                id.name = decl.name
                return id
            # TODO -- change to c_types.fieldDefinition
            # TODO -- this is very common... refactor
            if id in c_types.size_d:
                # typdef uint32 unsigned long;
                c_types.size_d[decl.name] = c_types.size_d[id]
                return c_types.size_d[decl.name]
            elif id in c_types.structs:
                return c_types.structs[id]
            elif not id:
                # unhandled cases, like enum
                return
            else:
                raise c_types.UnknownIdentifier(id)
        elif _type == FuncDecl:
            raise c_types.NotImplementede
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review. Please ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @Mat ok, moved question to codereview.stackexchange.con instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using type dispatching. As of Python 3.4, you can use a [dedicated decorator](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to do this. This decorator is available as a [backport package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/singledispatch) as well.

```
try:
    from functools import singledispatch
except ImportError:
    from singledispatch import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def build_struct(decl):
    # Don't know how to do the generic version
    return

@build_struct.register(TypeDecl)
def build_struct_typedecl(decl):
    return build_struct(decl.type)

@build_struct.register(IdentifierType)
def build_struct_identifier(decl)
    return " ".join(decl.names)

@build_struct.register(ID)
def build_struct_id(decl)
    return ['ID', decl.name]

# etc.
```

You can move the dispatch closer to the classes themselves; import the `build_struct` generic function and register more dispatch methods as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to build a recursive descent parser:

```
struct_actions = {
    TypeDecl: parse_type_decl,
    IdentifierType: parse_identifier_type,
    Etc: parse_etc,
}

def build_struct(decl):
    function = struct_actions.get(type(decl))
    if function is None:
        raise InvalidToken

    return function(decl)
```

Alternative, with a much more formal recursive descent parser that uses OO to build a syntax tree with heterogeneous objects:

http://www.llvmpy.org/llvmpy-doc/0.9/doc/kaleidoscope/PythonLangImpl2.html